# How to properly pass variable to Mule JDBC outbound endpoint

Tags: jdbc, mule

I am trying to pass an invocation variable to a dynamic jdbc-ee query without success.  If I replace the variable salesforcecontactcount with a hardcoded integer (ie: 1) in the query, it works fine.  While debugging, if I place a breakpoint on the query, it shows the variable is populating correctly.  I don't receive any error, the query just does not run.  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

I checked the database logs, and when I hard code the value for payloadsize, the query gets excecuted, but when I use the #[variable:salesforcecontactcount] the query does not get passed to the server although the driver does connect, it just doesn't send anything.

When looking at the debug output, I see the following when using the variable:

```
DEBUG 2013-10-22 00:44:58,048 [[salesforce_integration].dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.PreparedSqlCommandExecutor: Preparing batch for: INSERT INTO internal_request_history (executedon, source, type, payload, payloadsize) VALUES (now(), 'salesforce', 'contact', '', ?);
DEBUG 2013-10-22 00:44:58,048 [[salesforce_integration].dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.PreparedSqlCommandExecutor: Executing batch for: INSERT INTO internal_request_history (executedon, source, type, payload, payloadsize) VALUES (now(), 'salesforce', 'contact', '', ?);
DEBUG 2013-10-22 00:44:58,048 [[salesforce_integration].dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.PreparedSqlCommandExecutor: Command executed successfully: INSERT INTO internal_request_history (executedon, source, type, payload, payloadsize) VALUES (now(), 'salesforce', 'contact', '', ?);
```

When I hard code the value, the debug output is:

```
DEBUG 2013-10-22 00:48:16,186 [[salesforce_integration].dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.PreparedSqlCommandExecutor: Filling input parameters for: INSERT INTO internal_request_history (executedon, source, type, payload, payloadsize) VALUES (now(), 'salesforce', 'contact', '', 9);
DEBUG 2013-10-22 00:48:16,186 [[salesforce_integration].dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.PreparedSqlCommandExecutor: SQL: INSERT INTO internal_request_history (executedon, source, type, payload, payloadsize) VALUES (now(), 'salesforce', 'contact', '', 9); input params: []
DEBUG 2013-10-22 00:48:16,186 [[salesforce_integration].dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.PreparedSqlCommandExecutor: Registering output parameters for: INSERT INTO internal_request_history (executedon, source, type, payload, payloadsize) VALUES (now(), 'salesforce', 'contact', '', 9);
DEBUG 2013-10-22 00:48:16,186 [[salesforce_integration].dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.PreparedSqlCommandExecutor: Executing update: INSERT INTO internal_request_history (executedon, source, type, payload, payloadsize) VALUES (now(), 'salesforce', 'contact', '', 9);
DEBUG 2013-10-22 00:48:16,188 [[salesforce_integration].dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.PreparedSqlCommandExecutor: Command executed successfully: INSERT INTO internal_request_history (executedon, source, type, payload, payloadsize) VALUES (now(), 'salesforce', 'contact', '', 9);
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Store Retrieved Objects">
  <add-message-property key="salesforcecontactcount" value="#[payload.size()]"/>
</message-properties-transformer>

<jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="logRequestHistory"  queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="aclu_ads_db" doc:name="Log the Request">
  <jdbc-ee:query key="logRequestHistory" value="INSERT INTO internal_request_history (executedon, source, type, payload, payloadsize) VALUES (now(), 'salesforce', 'contact', '', #[variable:salesforcecontactcount]);  "/>
</jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>

<logger message="count: #[salesforcecontactcount]" level="INFO" doc:name="LoggerMessage"></logger>
```

**EDIT:** OK, I guess I am getting closer to an answer, if I change the query to be a SELECT instead of an INSERT, it works fine with the param being passed in:

```
<jdbc-ee:query key="logRequestHistory" value="SELECT * FROM internal_request_history WHERE payloadsize = #[variable:salesforcecontactcount];"/>
```

**ADDITIONALEDIT:** If I execute a stored procedure, I get the same 'non-result' as the insert and the same debug pattern:

```
<jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="logRequestHistory"  queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="aclu_ads_db" doc:name="Log the Request">
   <jdbc-ee:query key="logRequestHistory" value="CALL create_log('salesforce', 'contact', #[variable:salesforcecontactcount]);" />
</jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>

    DEBUG 2013-10-22 06:55:00,576 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Preparing batch for: { CALL create_log('salesforce', 'contact', ?); }
    DEBUG 2013-10-22 06:55:00,576 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Executing batch for: { CALL create_log('salesforce', 'contact', ?); }
    DEBUG 2013-10-22 06:55:00,577 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Command executed successfully: { CALL create_log('salesforce', 'contact', ?); }
    DEBUG 2013-10-22 06:55:00,577 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy.BatchUpdateSqlStatementStrategy: Batch duration: 0.006
```

And if I hardcode the call to the database, this is what I get for the debug:

```
DEBUG 2013-10-22 07:10:47,067 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Filling input parameters for: { CALL create_log('salesforce', 'contact', 5) }
DEBUG 2013-10-22 07:10:47,068 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.CallableSqlCommandExecutor: SQL: { CALL create_log('salesforce', 'contact', 5) } input params: []
DEBUG 2013-10-22 07:10:47,068 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Registering output parameters for: { CALL create_log('salesforce', 'contact', 5) }
DEBUG 2013-10-22 07:10:47,068 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Executing: { CALL create_log('salesforce', 'contact', 5) }
DEBUG 2013-10-22 07:10:47,069 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Command executed successfully: { CALL create_log('salesforce', 'contact', 5) }
DEBUG 2013-10-22 07:10:47,069 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Processing resultSets for: { CALL create_log('salesforce', 'contact', 5) }
DEBUG 2013-10-22 07:10:47,069 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Processed resultsets: 0
DEBUG 2013-10-22 07:10:47,070 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Processing output parameters for: { CALL create_log('salesforce', 'contact', 5) }
DEBUG 2013-10-22 07:10:47,070 [[salesforce_integration].aclu_ads_db.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy.ExecuteSqlStatementStrategy: Obtained result: {}
```

I think the problem comes down to the strategy being called.  How can I stop the query from using BatchUpdateSqlStatementStrategy?

Comment: If the insert fails there should be jdbc exception. Didn't you find them?

Comment: Nope, no jdbc exception gets thrown.  That's what's so confusing.  The thing is that the insert is never sent to the server even though the debug statement says it does.

Comment: I think the problem may come down to the strategy that is being used ExecuteSqlStatementStrategy vs BatchUpdateSqlStatementStrategy.

Comment: OK, I figured out a workaround.  The BatchUpdateSqlStatementStrategy is being called because the payload was an array.  It automatically will be called if that is the payload but then it expects the data to be passed as a list.  For now, I reset the payload to an empty string and store out the data I'll need later to variables.  This does seem very hackish to me - I'll leave the answer opened for a while and award to anyone who can tell me how to force the correct update strategy so that its using something other than BatchUpdateSqlStatementStrategy.

Answer (score 0):

@AlexGad
Indeed, this is an issue with Mule-EE, I noticed that Mule-CE works just fine.

When you call jdbc:outbound-endpoint with an ArrayList payload but use SESSION/INVOCATION variables as params in your SQL query, I noticed it has no effect on the table in question (no Insert/Update) yet logger records "Record Updated".
Changing payload to other type of an Object for this jdbc call solved the issue.
To keep an open mind, consider:
-passing SQL query parameters via a Payload instead
-consider message enrichers